# Loop over an array in array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In my React app (really basic at the moment) I have an array inside another array and I want to loop over all this content.
So far my code is:

```
 {recipes.map((recipe) => (
            <Recipe
                key={recipe.uid}
                title={recipe.data.title?.[0]?.text || null}
                description={recipe.data.intro?.[0]?.text || null}
                image={recipe.data.featured_image.url || null}
                imageAlt={recipe.data.featured_image.alt || null}
                aventuraTitle={recipe.data.tipo_aventura[0].tipo_titulo?.[0]?.text || null}
            />
        ))}
```

In this code I want aventuraTitle show all the tipo_titulo?.[0]?.text that exist.

As you can imagine this show only the first title.

My console log is:
[image]

I don't know what is the best way to loop over this array in React. Could you please advise me?
If you need any extra information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 {recipes.map((recipe) => (
            <Recipe
                key={recipe.uid}
                title={recipe.data.title?.[0]?.text || null}
                description={recipe.data.intro?.[0]?.text || null}
                image={recipe.data.featured_image.url || null}
                imageAlt={recipe.data.featured_image.alt || null}
                aventuraTitles={recipe.data.tipo_aventura}
            />
        ))}
```

Then in the `Recipe` component receive `aventuraTitles` as a prop which will be having an array.

You can use `map` on that the same way you did with the `Recipe` component.

Comment: Thank you for your help
I'm getting the error below:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {tipo_imagen, tipo_titulo, tipo_enlace}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Okay you have one more nested array. Then you can have one more nested map inside of one map.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<Recipe/>` component you need to `map` **tipo_titulo** array to view all the texts you need to view and pass `aventuraTitle={recipe.data.tipo_aventura[0].tipo_titulo || null}` to your `<Receipe/>` component as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do another map to just get the text strings and pass them down as another prop:

```
 {recipes.map((recipe) => (
            <Recipe
                key={recipe.uid}
                title={recipe.data.title?.[0]?.text || null}
                description={recipe.data.intro?.[0]?.text || null}
                image={recipe.data.featured_image.url || null}
                imageAlt={recipe.data.featured_image.alt || null}
                aventuraTitle={recipe.data.tipo_aventura[0].tipo_titulo?.map(x => x?.text || null)}
            />
        ))}
```

You can also pull this up to be a variable too to reduce the code a bit

```
 {recipes.map((recipe) => {

const tipo_titulo = recipe.data.tipo_aventura[0].tipo_titulo?.map(x => x?.text || null);

return (
            <Recipe
                key={recipe.uid}
                title={recipe.data.title?.[0]?.text || null}
                description={recipe.data.intro?.[0]?.text || null}
                image={recipe.data.featured_image.url || null}
                imageAlt={recipe.data.featured_image.alt || null}
                aventuraTitle={tipo_titulo }
            />
        )}
)}
```

Comment: Thanks!
That show me only the first tipo_titulo. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you need to iterate over `tipo_aventura` as well?